# How does virtual photon exchange lead to the attraction of opposite charges?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-interpretations, interactions, virtual-particles

This wonderful page in the physics FAQ, from 1994, by Matt McIrvin

http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Quantum/virtual_particles.html

explains how the exchange of virtual photons leads to attraction of charges of opposite sign. I tried to contact Matt, but without success. I searched for papers, but had no success either.

Is there any literature on this topic available - on the same level of understanding? Maybe a textbook section, or a didactical paper?

Comment: Matt's article is pretty good, but you really can't say too much more on this topic without getting into the mathematics. If there are specific things in that article that you don't quite follow, then maybe people here can help with that. This question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/217126/123208 is kind of on the same topic, but it doesn't go into details like Matt's article does, so I won't suggest it as a duplicate target for your question.